Lost ETH using BOT
I am a newbie and saw a video in YouTube about setting up ETH contract using BOT. The code was also given by the YouTuber. I created the contract and linked it to MetaMask and then transferred ETH to the contract and ran the BOT. After adding ETH, I didn't see ETH reflected in the contract. But I saw an internal transaction that showed ETH was transferred to another address. In the code provided, I didn't see anything related to a transfer. Is there a way to recover that lost ETH? I know in most of the forums the answer is "No" but trying to console myself. :( I can post the addresses through which ETH moved from the contract.

This is the code provided in the Youtube video:

This is the YouTube video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0H3B18yaNo8
